# Neatly pass positional arguments as args and optional arguments as kwargs from argparse to a function

Tags: python, argparse, args, keyword-argument

I would like to write a Python script that takes some necessary positional and some optional command-line arguments via `argparse`:

- Let's call the positional args `a`,`b`,`c`, and the optional arguments `x`,`y`,`z`.
- In my Python script, I would like to pass these args on to a function; specifically, I want `a`,`b`,`c` to be passed as `*args`, and `x`,`y`,`z` to be passed as `**kwargs`, the latter retaining their names.
- I would like to do this many times with different functions and different numbers of positional and optional arguments. Is there a neat, flexible, and/or pythonic way to do this?

Here is some example code:

```
import argparse

def parse():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('a', help='1st arg')
    parser.add_argument('b', help='2nd arg')
    parser.add_argument('c', help='3rd arg')
    parser.add_argument('-x', '--x', help='1st kwarg')
    parser.add_argument('-y', '--y', help='2nd kwarg')
    parser.add_argument('-z', '--z', help='3rd kwarg')
    return parser.parse_args()

def func(*args, **kwargs):
    a, b, c = args
    print 'a=', a
    print 'b=', b
    print 'c=', c
    for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
        print '%s=' % k, v

if __name__ == '__main__':

    all_args = parse()
    ### need to split all_args into args and kwargs here ###
    func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "many times with different functions and different numbers of ... arguments"? I think you're going to have to provide an example of how you would call your function, along with what the script would do with the arguments passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Namespace` you get back from `parse_args` will have attributes corresponding to each of your arguments. There will be no distinction between the positional arguments and the optionals, e.g.:

```
args
Namespace(a='1',b='one',x='foo', y=...)
```

Which, as is well documented, can be accessed as:

```
args.a
args.x
etc.
```

The `Namespace` can also be turned into a dictionary:

```
vars(args)
{'a'='1', 'b'='one', etc.}
```

You can pass the dictionary to a function as `**kwargs`.  That's standard Python argument practice.

If you want to pass some arguments as `*args` you'll have to split those off the `Namespace` or dictionary yourself.  Nothing in `argparse` will do that for you.

You could write a function like (not tested):

```
def split_args(args):
   vargs = vars(args)
   alist = ['a','b','c']
   args1 = []
   for a in alist:
        v = vargs.pop(a)
        args1.append(v)
   return args1, vars
```

Or more compactly, put the `pop` in a list comprehension:

```
In [702]: vargs = dict(a=1,b=3,c=4,x=5,y=3,z=3)
In [703]: [vargs.pop(a) for a in ['a','b','c']]
Out[703]: [1, 3, 4]
In [704]: vargs
Out[704]: {'y': 3, 'x': 5, 'z': 3}

In [705]: def foo(*args,**kwargs):
   .....:     print(args)
   .....:     print(kwargs)
   .....:     
In [706]: vargs = dict(a=1,b=3,c=4,x=5,y=3,z=3)
In [707]: foo(*[vargs.pop(a) for a in ['a','b','c']],**vargs)
(1, 3, 4)
{'x': 5, 'z': 3, 'y': 3}
```

### Further idea using custom Action class

The `parser` determines whether an argument is an `optional` vs. `positional` by its `option_strings` attribute. `add_argument` returns an `Action` subclass, which will have attributes like:

```
MyAction(option_strings=[], dest='baz', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
```

This is a `positional` because `option_strings` is an empty list.

```
MyAction(option_strings=['-m', '--mew'], dest='mew', nargs=None,...)
```

is an `optional` because that list is not empty.

The parser matches input strings with the `option_strings` and `nargs`, and then passes values to the `__call__` method of the matching `Action`.  This method is defined like:

```
def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
    setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)
```

This is the default `store` action.  The values are put in the `Namespace` as the `dest` attribute.

The `option_string` parameter is the string that triggered this call, something like '-m' or '--mew', or `None` for a `positional`.  The defined action types don't make use of this, but a user-defined Action class could do something.

```
class MyAction(argparse._StoreAction):
   def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
       # store option_string along with values in the Namespace
       setattr(namespace, self.dest, [values,option_string])
```

Or you could do something special with `positionals`, e.g.

```
       if option_string is None:
           # append values to a `star_args` attribute
           # rather than self.dest
```

With an action like this `positionals` could be accessed after parsing as:

```
args.star_args
```

The parser does maintain a list attribute like this.  The `extras` that `parse_known_args` returns are stored temporarily in the `Namespace` in the '_UNRECOGNIZED_ARGS_ATTR' attribute.

Comment: I wondered whether there was some nice pythonic way to do the splitting. Is there nothing in argparse that differentiates optional and positional arguments?

Comment: There must be, because `print_help` knows.  Look in `parser._action_groups` (dragons)

Comment: @user1637894: Any particular reason you need to distinguish required and optional arguments when passing them to the internal function? There's nothing stopping you from providing required arguments as keyword arguments.

Comment: Actually, you can't always do that (an example is with `self` for methods).  But I doubt that applies here.

Comment: No reason other than curiosity. I've accepted your answer, but I would still like to know.

Comment: Internally `argparse` distinguishes between positionals and optionals.  I could describe that reasoning if it helps.  But that distinction is not used in the `Actions` that insert values into the `namespace`.  You are trying to make `argparse` more like `optparse`.

Comment: To make it more like `optparse`, omit the positionals, and use `parse_known_args`.

Comment: Thanks, that's sufficient. Curiosity sated.

Comment: I have sketched an idea of how you could use  a custom `Action` class to store all the `positionals` in a custom namespace attribute list.